# Focus back to Excel once email has been created with VBA

Tags: excel, email, vba

I have a VBA macro which does the following:

1. Creates a report, saves it to main directory. Closes the report
2. Creates various emails, attaches the report to each (doesn't send the email)
3. Msgbox shows up showing that process is finished

The thing is that, once the whole process is finished, I want the user to know it is done, but this code doesn't return the focus to excel (which I hoped would be the problem)

```
Windows(the_current_window).Activate
Worksheets(currentQuoteSheet).Select
```

The last email created is what stays on screen. The msgbox doesn't come up, only if I click on excel icon on the menu bar it does. So users are there just waiting to finish (when it has, in fact  :(  )

Any ideas how to make sure the msgbox shows up after last email is created without users having to click on excel?

Comment: not sure what your whole code looks like, but you'll need to `Activate` the Excel application before displaying the message box. Also, since you closed the report (which I assume is an XL file), using `Worksheets(currentQuoteSheet).Select` won't work, since the sheet is closed. But maybe that is a sheet from another workbook you have open.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try

```
sub doSomething()
   'do something
   AppActivate "Microsoft Excel"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 8):

I am on MS Office 365 and for some reason I get an Application Error when trying `AppActivate "Microsoft Excel"` and `AppActivate "Excel"`, however:

```
AppActivate Application.Caption
```

Worked for me.

Comment: That is the way!

Answer (score 1):

Although this works to a degree, it doesn't activate the MSGbox to allow one to press y/n on the keyboard (you can with the mouse).

This allows keyboard interaction if you are doing the task repetitively and don't want to grab your mouse.  Tested Office 2013 (64bit) (remove PtrSafe  if you are 32bit)

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function MessageBox _
        Lib "User32" Alias "MessageBoxA" _
           (ByVal hWnd As Long, _
            ByVal lpText As String, _
            ByVal lpCaption As String, _
            ByVal wType As Long) _
        As Long
Sub Test
        'Call showwindow(ActiveWorkbook.Name)
        AppActivate "Excel"
        'I need this to retain the focus
        retval = MessageBox(&O0, "Do you want to process", "My Question", vbYesNo + vbSystemModal)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried calling your workbook by name?  Something like:

```
Workbooks("EXCEL WORKBOOK NAME.XLS").Activate
```

Comment: Hi, this didn't work unfortunately, you need to click on Excel before the message comes up.

Answer (score 0):

This drove me nuts last night, and I kept going to sites by Microsoft and such that said to use AppActivate("Excel") or AppActivate("Microsoft Excel"), neither of which would work.

Looking at this, I assumed that I was calling the app name.  I needed to switch focus back to Microsoft Excel, which is why I was calling it in the AppActive statement.  But that's not the case.

You're calling the window **title**.  Now if you open a new Excel workbook it starts (in Office 365) with the name "Book1 - Excel".  And it is the word "Excel" in the window title that AppActivate is looking for when you use the code AppActiveate("Excel").  But I already saved my file, and its name was stored in a variable called ShortDocName.  So when I switched my code to ready AppActiave(ShortDocName) it worked as intended.

Answer (score 0):

You can also call the application. When I need to do this I query the application and place it in a variable

```
ThisFile = ActiveWorkbook.Name
```

and the activate the file, which activates the Window

```
AppActivate (ThisFile)
```